# Grid with locked column not displayed

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4.1

I am trying to insert a data grid with a locked column in a web application.

If I display the grid without locked columns, everything runs fine. When I make a column locked, the gird gets created, but it is very small(just a tiny square, making it basically invisible).

Why does this happen and how can i fix it?

Here is what I have:

```
for (var i = 0; i < this.fields.length; i++) {
    var currentField = this.fields[i];
    fields.push(currentField.columnName);
    columns.push({
        header: currentField.name,
        dataIndex: currentField.columnName,
        hidden: i >= 4,
        locked: i == 1
    });
}
Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    storeId: 'resultsStore',
    fields: fields,
    data: results
});
var grid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    store: "resultsStore",
    columns: columns,
    title: 'Results',
    renderTo: "actualResultsContainer",
    height: 250,
    width: 500,
    enableLocking: true,
});
```

**EDIT** If I try to re-create everything(repeat all actions from above after rendering), the grid gets created and from this point on, it runs just fine. What am I missing?

Comment: What happens if you create the store and keep it as a variable...
    var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {...
    var grid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
        store: store,

and then remove enableLocking?  Does the grid display?  Any errors?

Comment: Couple things: `enableLocking` don't need to be specified if you have `locked: true` in the columns definition. And I'm not sure - but I think you can only lock first column, and looks like you're trying to lock the second one, no?

Comment: @JohnMoses I have tried what you said, but nothing happened. Still the same problem.

Comment: @sha I have deleted the `enableLocking` and the number of column has nothing to do with this. If a column is `locked`, it will be moved to the left. In order to be sure of this, I have tried to make the first column `locked`, but the issue persisted.

Comment: I would try to simplify things - move columns declaration inside grid declaration. Don't use loops and other objects - just define columns manually.

Comment: @sha The columns are created dynamically. Defining them manually would not be possible, because their names and number depend on various things(like the user's role) and are not always the same.

Comment: I understand that. But for testing purposes to figure out what's wrong - can you do this?

Comment: @sha I have tried defining them as you said, but it didn't help. I have discovered another thing: please check my edited post.

Comment: It's hard to say what's wrong without seeing more code from you. How is the grid rendered? What's the html page looks like?

Comment: The grid is created as shown above, when a button is clicked. It's container is just a div, with seemingly no special properties. What exactly should I be looking for?

Comment: Where is div defined? Is it rendered when you're pressing the button and creating a grid?

Comment: @sha I was creating the div with jQuery. I have now hardcoded the div into the html file and it seems to be working. To my mind, the div wasn't created synchronously, and it might not have been there when the grid was to be created. Please post an answer, so I can accept it. Thank you!

Comment: So it basically didn't have anything to do with locking, but timing of div and grid creation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work the way you wrote it. Check that `div` you're rendering grid to is created in a timely manner.

Comment: It still seems strange to me that only when I have locked columns, it doesn't really find the div. If this was the case, then the issue should have occurred even when there were no locked columns(I hope my explanation is clear enough :D). Anyway, it seems to be fixed now and although it might not be a good idea, I'm going to leave it as it is.